# Check if the list is empty

Tags: python

```
def gt(nums, n):

    for c in nums:
        if max(nums) > n:
            return True

        elif max(nums) < n:
            return False

        elif not nums:
            return False
```

for the last `elif`, it should validate the list of nums whether it is empty or not. But not working for me. Does anyone know what code i can use to check if the list is empty?
Thanks.

Comment: See the [`len`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) function.

Comment: What should happen if `max(nums) == n`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I don't think these answers will work for you because it's not clear what the intended behavior you want is.  Are you trying to check if all the values in nums are greater than n?  If so, you need to be sure that you don't return True until the loop is finished.

Comment: there's no reason to loop through nums if your not checking individual elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check for `not nums` first. And you don't need a `for` loop.

Note that this (like your code) doesn't explicitly check for `max(nums) == n`, returning `False` in this situation (which I think should be the correct behaviour for a function called `gt()`):

```
def gt(nums, n):
    if not nums:
        return False
    return max(nums) > n
```

---

**EDIT:** Some timings (Python 2.7.3):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> all = """l = list(range(100))
... rl = list(reversed(range(100)))
... """
>>> tim = all + """def gt(nums, n):
...     if not nums:
...         return False
...     return max(nums) > n"""
>>> gnibbler = all + """def gt(nums, n):
...     return any(x>n for x in nums)"""
>>> burhan = all + """def gt(nums, n):
...   return max(nums) > n if nums else False"""
>>> # Test with the condition being False:
... timeit.timeit(setup=tim, stmt="gt(l, 100)")
3.011574096311698
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=gnibbler, stmt="gt(l, 100)")
8.00847921677337
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=burhan, stmt="gt(l, 100)")
2.9805757305956178
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=tim, stmt="gt(rl, 100)")
2.8600606448831307
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=gnibbler, stmt="gt(l, 100)")
7.997938412127745
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=burhan, stmt="gt(l, 100)")
3.032805185133668
>>> # Now what if the condition is True?
... timeit.timeit(setup=tim, stmt="gt(l, 98)")
2.98623750798793
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=gnibbler, stmt="gt(l, 98)")
8.265056412191534
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=burhan, stmt="gt(l, 98)")
2.9731271156252888
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=tim, stmt="gt(rl, 98)")
2.8777295865334764
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=gnibbler, stmt="gt(rl, 98)")
1.0481696827076092
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=burhan, stmt="gt(rl, 98)")
2.8776150752220246
```

So Burhan's and my solution are equivalent in terms of speed (not really surprising since they do exactly the same thing, mine is just a bit more verbose), and gnibbler's is noticeably faster *only if* the list is long enough (I've removed previous timings where it way always slower when the list only contained ten items), the condition evaluates to `True` *and*  the search value is reached very early in the list. Otherwise, all the Python-level comparisons will slow it down a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Your method can be simplified to:

```
def gt(nums, n):
  return max(nums) > n if nums else False

>>> gt([],0)
False
>>> gt([1,2,3],6)
False
>>> gt([1,2,3],1)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

`max()` is forced to search through the entire of `nums` even if the first or second element is greater than `n`. `any()` will return immediately when an element greater than `n` is found

```
def gt(nums, n):
    return any(x>n for x in nums)
```

#### Test cases

```
>>> gt([],0)
False
>>> gt([1,2,3],6)
False
>>> gt([1,2,3],1)
True
```

Comment: Good point, +1. On the other hand, if you have a long array where only the last item is greater than `n`, you'd be doing a lot of comparisons. Not sure which would be faster...

Comment: Huh. I've just done a few timing tests with surprising results. Can you explain this? I would have expected your solution to be much faster.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, `max` does a lot of comparisons anyway, but they are done at "C" level, so are much faster than a generator expression for short lists. In CPython you will see the best case favouring `any` when the list gets to about ~100 elements. pypy may have closer results. You can improve the speed of `any` somewhat by using `imap`, `partial` and `operator`. On the otherhand if `nums` is itself a generator, `any` might save the expense of generating numbers that you don't really need to.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've re-run the tests with longer lists. Now you can see a significant performance increase in the best-case scenario for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are conflating other languages' need to loop over an array (a list or tuple or other sequence in Python) with the [max](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) function.

Max() in Python takes a list or sequence and returns the max value. Note -- no need to loop:

```
>>> max([1,2,3])
3
>>> l=[1,2,22]
>>> max(l)
22
>>> max('abc')
'c'
```

So your function can be done this way:

```
def gt(nums, n): 
    if nums and max(nums) > n:
        return True
    return False
```

Or, if max is taken away from you, or you just want to see a loop for this:

```
def gt(nums, n): 
    for num in nums:
        if num>n:
            return True   

    return False
```

Now you do not need to check the list being empty because if it is the for loop is never executed.

One final form to consider:

```
>>> nums=[1,5,5,1,5,1,1,1]
>>> n=2
>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(nums) if x>n]
[1, 2, 4]
```

This is a list of the index of each element of nums where that element is greater than n using a list comprehension and enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> plist = []
>>> not plist
True
```

`not list` works for me

Answer (score -1):

The control wont go inside the loop if nums was empty. So, you can neglect that check (unless you are modifying nums inside the same loop, which is not recommended)

However, to answer your question, use:

```
nums == []
```

Comment: `nums == []` should probably be avoided: the rest of the code (if it made sense, anyway) would be equally happy with tuples or sets.